# About $Im T^k \cap Ker T^k$ for a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that we have a linear operator $T:X\rightarrow X $ on finite dimensional space $X$.  Let for $ k\in \mathbb N$:  $M_k=Im T^k$, $N_k=Ker T^k$. Since $dim X<\infty$ there is a positive integer $p$ such that
$$M_1 \varsupsetneq M_2 \varsupsetneq M_3 \varsupsetneq ...\varsupsetneq M_p=M_{p+1}=...  $$
and
$$
N_1 \varsubsetneq N_2 \varsubsetneq N_3 \varsubsetneq ...\varsubsetneq N_p=N_{p+1}=...
$$
By fitting lemma $X=M_p \oplus N_p$.

I wish to prove that  for $k<p$ we have $M_k+N_k \neq X$ or equivalently $M_k \cap N_k \neq \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M_k \cap N_k = \{0\}$ and $a \in N_{k + 1}$ but $\notin N_k$

Then $T^k(a) \ne 0 \in M_k$ and $T^k(a) \in N_k$.

Contradaction.